# How do I send an email with an attachment without first creating a file using ruby-gmail?

Tags: ruby, gmail

I'm using the [ruby-gmail](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail) gem to send mails.

What I'd like to do is send a ruby hash as a json file.

Example:

```
require 'gmail'
require 'json'

hash = {'foo' => 'bar}

Gmail.new(<EMAIL>, <PASSWORD>) do |gmail|
  gmail.deliver do
    to <RECIPIENT>
    subject <SUBJECT>
    text_part do
      body <EMAIL MESSAGE>
    end
    add_file hash.to_json
  end
end
```

When I try this it simply sends the mail without the attachment.

What could I try next?

**Edit:**

I want to do this without first creating a file.

Comment: No, I knew I could send an attachment if I first saved a file. I'm still looking for a way to do this without first saving.

Comment: What about creating the file, attaching it and then deleting it after sending it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create the file before you can send it in your `add_file` method:

```
hash = {'foo' => 'bar'}
File.open("filename.json","w") do |f|
  f.write(hash.to_json)
end
```

then:

```
Gmail.new(<EMAIL>, <PASSWORD>) do |gmail|
  gmail.deliver do
    to <RECIPIENT>
    subject <SUBJECT>
    text_part do
      body <EMAIL MESSAGE>
    end
    add_file 'path/to/filename.json`
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this without first creating a file?

Comment: `#to_json` just changes data structures, it doesn't create a file which the gmail gem needs in order to make an attachment.  does it need to be an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "gmail" gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/gmail), then you can add a file with name and content parameters rather than having to actually create a local file. For example:

```
Gmail.connect(<EMAIL>, <PASSWORD>) do |gmail|
   gmail.deliver do
     to(<RECIPIENT>)
     subject(<SUBJECT>)
     text_part do
       body(<TEXT_BODY>)
     end
     html_part do
        content_type('text/html; charset=UTF-8')
        body(<HTML_BODY>)
     end

     add_file({filename: <FILE_NAME>, content: <FILE_CONTENT>})
   end
end
```